# Cannot read property 'backdrop' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

This is code I'm using in my HTML page. In my angular module I import every relevant things. But always says this error because of backdrop. Please help. I have no idea about this backdrop.If some can explain please what is this error and why it comes ?

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> Bootstrap Modals
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <!-- Button trigger modal -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" (click)="smallModal.show()">
        Launch small modal
      </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-->
      </div>
      <!--/.row-->
    </div>

    <div bsModal #smallModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" (click)="smallModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="smallModal.hide()">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
```

**This is my .ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal/modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mso-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './mso-user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mso-user-profile.component.css']
})
export class MsoUserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'backdrop' of undefined

Comment: You should edit your question instead of commenting with an important part of your question

Comment: thank you all i edited my code

Comment: backdrop is usually a therm for a 'veil' behind a dialog/popup modal window. It's clear from your template that you are displaying some kind of modal but the class code is not relevant. Post the relevant code or which third party ocde you are using

Comment: I can not understand. this is the html and ts code there

Comment: Is this the only code you have?

Comment: No. But I can not put whole code here. This is the relevant component codes

Comment: It's obvious this is not a relevant code, you can see by yourself. You don't need to put the whole code. Trying to find the relevant part will maybe help you realise where the issue is. Otherwise make a plunker. At this point nobody can help you

Comment: @Vega I created a component by CLI . and this is It's HTML file TS file.

Comment: I still tell you you haven't posted the relevant code, for example where is smallModal? Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @Vega Yes ! Bootstrap

Answer (score 6):

Trigger modal ID and modal ID not present.

**Your code 1**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" (click)="smallModal.show()">
```

**I suggest 1**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" **data-target="#YourModalName"**>Launch demo modal</button>
```

**Your code 2**

```
<div bsModal #smallModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

**I suggest 2**

```
<div class="modal fade" **id="YourModalName"** tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In my case I had this correct approach, however, the Offcanvas was a child component and at the moment of the button click it was not in the DOM yet, due to a condition. Once I changed this condition, it started working.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to load component dynamically by factory like below:

```
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(YOURModalComponent);
const componentRef = this.fileAttacherContainer.createComponent(factory);
const component = componentRef.instance;
```

You have to wait till the component creation complete by the factory resolver, I mean when the component doesn't create yet then initialize of ngx-bootstrap backdrop not called, for example if you call your show modal like below everything goes well:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    component.show();
}, 2000); //any millisecond
```

But, do not forget this is a bad solution, but I told for your better understanding.

Finally, the good solution is using Promises or simply call `component.show();` in `ngAfterViewInit` of your child component.

By the way, read this article too:
https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked

Answer (score 0):

import this class:

```
// RECOMMENDED
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
// or
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Offcanvas was a child component and at the moment of the button click it was not in the DOM yet, due to a condition. Once I changed this condition, it started working.

Here an example with Bootstrap 5 and Angular 15:

// component with button which activates the Offcanvas

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#YourModalName">

...

<child-component *ngIf="data$ | async as data" [data]="data"/>
```

// child-component with the Offcanvas HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="YourModalName" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```